# How to force GPU memory to 0 on a headless server

Tags: headless, raspi-config, memory, gpu, memory-split

Is there any way to force the shared memory to `0`? I'm running Jessie on a pi3 (and a pi2 and a few zero-w's) as a headless server and only ever access it via SSH or a WebUI for certain services. I just do not see any reason to keep any memory reserved for a **G**PU.

Now I know that the [documentation states that the minimum is 16Mb](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/memory.md), and if you try to set it to 0 using `raspi-config`, it ignores you and resets to the default 64, but there must be a way to free up those last 16Mb to other services that will actually use it?

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible the Pi relies on the GPU for things like the undervoltage code which will run headless or not.

Comment: Hey @SteveRobillard, thanks for the feedback, I didn't know about the other processes needing the *"GPU"* to run. Thanks for that. This question is a bit like the other, but maybe worded a bit better making it more findable? Should I delete it?

Comment: Deleting it is up to you, but it is likely to be closed as a duplicate if left open.